# different results in C and C# with Sin and Cos

Tags: c#, c, trigonometry

I wrote a program to get the Angle in degrees between two gps-Positions. It works fine in C#, but it doesn`t in C. Where is the Problem?

Here is the code in C#

```
double lat1 = GetRAD(pos1.Latitude);
double lat2 = GetRAD(pos2.Latitude);
double long1 = GetRAD(pos1.Longitude);
double long2 = GetRAD(pos2.Longitude);

double angleAtCentre = Math.Acos(Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Sin(lat2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(long2 - long1));

double retVal = Math.Acos((Math.Sin(lat2) - Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Cos(angleAtCentre)) / (Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(angleAtCentre)));
retVal = retVal * 180.0 / Math.PI;
if (long1 > long2)
{
    retVal = retVal * (-1);
}

return retVal;
```

And here ia the code in C

```
double lat1 = GetRAD(pos1.latitude);
double lat2 = GetRAD(pos2.latitude);
double long1 = GetRAD(pos1.longitude);
double long2 = GetRAD(pos2.longitude);

double angleAtCentre = acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(long2 - long1));

double retVal = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(angleAtCentre)) / (cos(lat1) * sin(angleAtCentre)));
retVal = GetDEG(retVal);
if(long1 > long2)
    {
    retVal = retVal * (-1);
}
return retVal;
```

I tried it with the Coordinates: Pos1 (47.0998194N, 9.8605694E), Pos2 (47.1004972N, 9.8600639E)
The correct result in C# is -26.9 degree, in C I get something like -88

Comment: Where is the definition for the function called `GetDEG` in C?

Comment: `retVal = retVal * (-1);` should be `retVal = -retVal;`

Comment: Why do you only show part of the code? The errors could well be in the parts of the code you did not show.

Comment: Show the definition of `GetRad` and `getDEG` for the C example.

Answer (score 0):

You titled your question:

> Different results in C and C# with Sin and Cos

However, you can rest assured that the standard library functions in both languages perform trigonometry correctly. The expressions in the code in the question are the same in the two versions. Ergo, the difference behaviour must come from the degrees/radians conversion functions, whose code you omitted.

The ratio of your two values, `-88` and `-26.9` is `3.27` which is quite close to `π`. So my guess is that you C implementation of `GetDEG` is incorrect. I suspect that you have written it like this:

```
deg = rad * 180.0;
```

But it needs to be:

```
deg = rad * 180.0 / pi;
```

If you include `math.h` then you will be able to use `M_PI` for π. or if your `math.h` does not define `M_PI`, then you can define it yourself. You can write degree/radians conversion functions like this:

```
double rad2deg(double rad)
{
    return rad * 180.0 / M_PI;
}

double deg2rad(double deg)
{
    return deg * M_PI / 180.0;
}
```

One final comment is that negating a number is usually performed by using the unary form of the `-` operator, rather than multiplication:

```
retVal = -retVal;
```

This reads a lot more clearly than your code and matches how the expression would be written mathematically.

A complete program that demonstrates this is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

double rad2deg(double rad)
{
    return rad * 180.0 / M_PI;
}

double deg2rad(double deg)
{
    return deg * M_PI / 180.0;
}

double angleBetween(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
    double angleAtCentre = acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(long2 - long1));
    double retVal = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(angleAtCentre)) / (cos(lat1) * sin(angleAtCentre)));
    return long1 > long2 ? -retVal : retVal;
}

int main(void)
{
    double angle = angleBetween(
        deg2rad(47.0998194), deg2rad(9.8605694), 
        deg2rad(47.1004972), deg2rad(9.8600639)
    );
    printf("%f\n", rad2deg(angle));
}
```

**Output**

```
-26.915686
```

I suggest that you run this program on your system to see for yourself that it gives the desired output.

---

**Update**

You claim in the comments that the program above produces the output `-92` on your system. If that is really the case, then the issue is indeed related to your system. Although, your claim does seem a little far fetched to me, but if your system really outputs that value, then it is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers. But I did the calculation of rad-values correct. I still have the problem. Is it possible that it the values are different because I`m running the C-Code on a Mikrokontrollerboard? Maybe with the clockrate? I tried to switch the Positions, like that: Pos1 (47.1004972N,9.8600639E), Pos2 (47.0998194N, 9.8605694E). The correct Result ist 153 degrees, the C-program results 91

Comment: What I say above is all I will say until you can provide complete code. I don't understand why you ask for help and then conceal vital information. Do you want help or not?

Comment: If you really doubt your C compiler, run the program in my answer on your system.

Comment: Ok, sorry. And Thanks for your help again. It really seems to be the C compiler. I tried your code and I got -92 after calculateing it in degree.

Comment: My program, run without change, on your system yields the value `-92`?

Comment: yes, I only added this: retVal = rad2deg(retVal); bevore I return it

Comment: That's a different program though, isn't it. Try running my program.

Comment: double angleBetween(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
 double angleAtCentre = acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(long2 - long1));
 double retVal = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(angleAtCentre)) / (cos(lat1) * sin(angleAtCentre)));
 retVal = rad2deg(retVal);
 return long1 > long2 ? -retVal : retVal;
}

Comment: Again, I won't engage in this game. Please run my program unmodified.

Comment: I did, it returns -92

Comment: It's just that your previous comments state that you modified the program.

Answer (score -1):

Your subroutines are wrong. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double lat1 = 47.0998194 * 0.0174532925;
    double lat2 = 47.1004972 * 0.0174532925;
    double long1 = 9.8605694 * 0.0174532925;
    double long2 = 9.8600639 * 0.0174532925;

    double angleAtCentre = acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(long2 - long1));

    double retVal = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(angleAtCentre)) / (cos(lat1) * sin(angleAtCentre)));
    retVal = retVal * 180.0 / 3.1415;
    if(long1 > long2){
        retVal = retVal * (-1);
    }

    printf("value: %f\n", retVal);
}
```

The `0.0174532925` multiplier is for converting degrees to radians. And the output:

```
value: -26.916409
```

Voila..

Next time you post a question make sure to include your subroutines and also the structure for whatever `pos1` and `pos2` is. Also assuming you include `math.h`.

Comment: That's quite an unusual value of π

Comment: It is well justified, it's just that copy-paste seemed reasonable enough for answering a stack overflow question..

Comment: Obviously the basic idea in your answer is right. However, you can expect to get judged on basic practices. And using made up values for π and injecting magic constants are likely to incur disapproval. I guess answerers are expected to show a high standard of coding and follow reasonable practices, and not be sloppy. I doubt that you really use `3` in your programs! Since `M_PI` exists in `math.h` that's the thing to use. Or even if it did not you could write `PI` in the code and allow the asker to fill in the value. Semantically that would be clear.

Comment: All that said, I got a downvote too, so perhaps somebody took exception to us answering without actually being able to see the deficient implementation of the asker's `GetDEG`. Hey ho.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers. But I did the calculation of rad-values correct. I still have the problem. Is it possible that it the values are different because I`m running the C-Code on a Mikrokontrollerboard? Maybe with the clockrate? I tried to switch the Positions, like that: Pos1 (47.1004972N,9.8600639E), Pos2 (47.0998194N, 9.8605694E). The correct Result ist 153 degrees, the C-program results 91

Comment: I wouldn't trust those microcontroller C compilers too much especially the ones for PIC.. try changing doubles to floats

Comment: Please note that the two longitudes are quite similar, so subtracting them will cause a loss of precision. This is a known problem with the spherical cosine law. The haversine formula is preferred.